# Problem Converting Fiscal Year to Calendar Dates

Tags: ms-access-2016

I need help using a query to convert Fiscal year to Calendar Year. For Example, I have the Fiscal_Year column and Fiscal_Quarter Column, as shown below

```
Fiscal_Year  Fiscal_Qtr  Calendar_Year
FY21         4Q  
FY22         4Q  
FY21         2Q  
FY24         4Q  
FY24         2Q
```

I need help coming up with a query of converting the Fiscal year to normal calendar dates group of Month/Date/Year(mm/dd/yyyy). if it is Fiscal_Year FY21 and Fiscal_Qtr is 4Q, then the date should be 9/30/2021, and if it is Fiscal_Year FY21 and Fiscal_Qtr is 2Q then the Calendar_Year should be 06/30/2021

Comment: Your sample data don't match.  So: 2021-06-30 -> 2021-03-31?

Comment: Basically I need help getting a query to return Fiscal year to a full calendar year if the Fiscal Year is FY21 to return 2021. So far I'm only working with FY21, FY22, and FY23. This was my first attempt, but I'm getting wrong somewhere. IIF([Sales Projection Year)=FY21, 2021or IIF([Sales Projection Year)=FY22, 2022, or IIF([Sales Projection Year)=FY23, 2023.

Comment: Sure, but if your fiscal year doesn't have four quarters, as your sample data indicates, it will not be possible.